# Hiding JUST sensitive data per country POWERBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas, row-level-security

I need some help on a problem , I have 3 tables Costumer and Customer-Contact with a Relationship with the CUSTID field and Users Table (with list of CUID of the users of the report) as showen in the model below :)

[DATAMODEL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLdVS.png)

I want to hide  JUST the sensitive data (email,First name and last name) but to see the customerID in both table   based on the country of the user(using username DAX function), but when I use this DAX in the role:
[DAX USED IN RLS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMnbH.png)

I hide also the CustomerID field =>I'm loosing data :/
[Not what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pWAT.png)

This is what I want for a user Connected from ITALY => seeing all the data of the model BUT just the sensitive data(Customer_CONTACT TABLE) of the ITALY (email+NAME) and for others sensitive data Blank as he is from ITALY.

[EXPECTATION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9ipE.png)

Could you please advice ?

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: "R" in "RLS" comes from ROW. It doesn't work on COLUMNS. RLS is not the right tool for this task.

Comment: @andrey can you please give me a solution or a path to search... Many thanks in advance